# uipageviewcontroller and uiwebview in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uiwebview, uipageviewcontroller

Here I have html content which is displayed using UIWebView. The webview is displayed in horizontal scrolling and which looks like scrolling page by page and currently I have implemented the normal pagecurl animation,Instead of using this animation I want to use the UIPageviewcontroller

```
CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
    [transition setDelegate:self];
    [transition setDuration:0.5f];
    if(flipType==0)
        [transition setType:@"pageUnCurl"];
    else {
        [transition setType:@"pageCurl"];
    }
    [transition setSubtype:@"fromRight"];
 [theWebView.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:@"CurlAnim"];
```

Could you help me to implement this.

Comment: what you want exactly?

Comment: Here I need Pagecurl animation which is similar to iBook app,It is applied to uiwebview

Answer (score 0):

Its really easy you could just have a webview as the view of the viewcontrollers added to the 
pageviewcontroller
there is an excellent tutorial about the same 
[here](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Example_iOS_5_iPhone_UIPageViewController_Application)
kindly go through it.

Comment: S sir,This is I have already tried,here only i have a problem which means [one Html file contains to 10 pages and another to 20 pages and etc].Here how can i apply the pagecurl animation in the  inside pages in uiwebview and after finished the first webview and goes to next

Comment: then could you explain a bit more on how you implemented pagecurl animation before like when and where did u initiate the pagecurl etc.